# Change the opacity of a cut selection (nemo.css)

Tags: themes, gtk, nemo, ambiance

I am trying to find what I need to edit in a **GTK theme** (specifically Ambiance) to change the opacity of a cut file. A selected file is orange and when I cut it, it is a little opaque - I'd like it to be more transparent, so that it is easily distinguishable.

I've played around with the `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css` but I haven't seen any difference.

Edit: I've created a `nemo.css` file inside the apps folder, properly imported it at `gtk-main.css`, but I can not find the variable I need to change.

Comment: Yes, this is it.

Comment: While this certainly helped, I had no luck finding the variable I need to change.

Comment: @Chris - what graphics chipset is this at your machine ?

Comment: NVIDIA, with the proprietary 352.41 driver. How does this help?

Comment: @Chris - is this of help ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860874/how-to-convert-hex-color-to-rgba-with-less-compiler

Comment: try adding css for the selection property
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162033/how-to-change-the-opacity-of-the-selected-text

Comment: have you looked at the gtk3 css API? You might also look at the library that provides those functions, sometimes there are undocumented features.  
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to create a small code inside theme folder exactly at:

`sudo vim /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/nemo.css`

*note:* change `vim` with your favourite text editor

```
.nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item:selected {
color: @theme_selected_fg_color;
background-image: none;
background:#778196;
}
```

Now we should give gtk-main a path to our file ,open the file at

`sudo vim  /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css`

add to the file

`@import url("apps/nemo.css");`

Save & close it.Reboot. That's it, done!